# Take input from excel and data need to be removed from text file

Tags: python, excel, linux, shell

I have below data in excel file `(data.xlsx)` more than `6000 rows` and i have many text files in my ubuntu system.

[image: Input excel file]

Text files directory structure:-

```
/home/user/excel/report/ML_PROJECT_APPLICATION_WRITE.txt
/home/user/excel/report/folder-1/ML_PROJECT_APPLICATION_OPEN.txt
/home/user/excel/report/folder-1/filepath/ML_PROJECT_UBUNTU_OPEN.txt
/home/user/excel/report/folder-2/ML_PROJECT_CENTOS_WRITE.txt
/home/user/excel/report/folder-3/ML_PROJECT_RHEL_WRITE.txt
```

One of the text file format as follows,

**ML_PROJECT_APPLICATION_WRITE.txt**

```
# //DEPOT/ABCD/PROJECT/Jerd
# Permission: WRITE

dreac.leoson
ritu.bhangale
makyen
markerikson.s
bernardo.pereira 
elitezen
```

The filename of the text files are matching excel sheet's `D` column. For each row, i want to a search text file as per `D` column and need to look the User-ID in `H` column, if user-id exists in that particular row matched text file then `user-id` need to be removed from that text file. Need help to achieve this in automated way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, import `data.xlsx` into a `pandas.DataFrame` and create a `dict` to map the file names and user ids:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
d = dict(zip(data["File Name"], data["User-ID"]))
```

Use a custom function to return the path of your file (with sub-directory):

```
import os
def find(name):
    for root, _, files in os.walk("/home/user/excel/report"):
        if name in files:
            return os.path.join(root, name)
```

Then, loop through the `dict` and transform your files as needed. First, read the file. Then, remove the user-id if it exists and write back to the file.

```
for file in d:
    fullname = find(f"{file}.txt")
    if fullname is not None:
        with open(fullname, "r") as f:
            contents = f.read().strip()
    
        with open(fullname, "w") as f:
            f.write(contents.replace(d[file], ""))
```

Note, if your files are in a different directory, make sure you specify the entire file path in `pd.read_excel` and `open`.

Comment: not_speshal, thank you. Files are in different directories under for example /home/user/excel/report/

Comment: Even this handles recursively the `text` files present inside sub-directories  of `/home/user/excel/report/` directory as well?

Comment: It is not able to find the `text files` exists under `home/user/excel/report/` its sub-directory.  Could you please help me to search inside its sub-directories as well?

Comment: Update your question with your folder structure and where to find each file.

Comment: i have updated the question with folder structure of `text files`.  As per `data.xlsx` file it need to search/find the `text file` in `/home/user/excel/report/` folder and its sub-folder.

Comment: Edited my answer - This works on a Windows PC. Please look to adapt for Ubuntu if needed.

Comment: Ok on windows what is the python version used?

Comment: Python 3.8.10 - If you have any further issues, please open a new question.